# Prolog: Replace list items using facts

Tags: prolog

im trying to make a function that loops through a list and replaces the element if it matches a fact.

I was able to implement a simple replacement that replaces every element in the list.

```
replace([X|T], Y, [Y|T2]) :- replace(T,Y,T2).
replace([],X,[X]).
```

so this just replaces every list item in X with Y.

Now i want to replace every list item in X using a fact like so:

```
replace([1,2,3], [ rule(1, [one]), rule(2, [two]) ], Result)
```

so if the list is `[1,2,3]`, the result will be `[one, two, 3]`

how would I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a second rule that goes through the list of replacements, and either picks the first one that matches, or leaves the item unchanged, like this:

```
replace([],_,[]).
replace([H|T], L, [RH|RT]) :- replace(T,L,RT), replace_one(H, L, RH).

replace_one(H, [], H).
replace_one(H, [rule(H,B)|_], B).
replace_one(H, [rule(A,_)|T], R) :- H \= A, replace_one(H, T, R).
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/4ZWE0y)

Answer (score 2):

I do prefer to use higher order library support

```
replace(In, Replacements, Out) :-
  maplist(replace_one(Replacements), In, Out).

replace_one(RepList, Rep, Val) :-
  memberchk(rule(Rep, [Val]), RepList) -> true ; Rep = Val.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be simply:

```
replace([], _, []).
replace([H|T], Rules, [R|TR]) :-
        (   memberchk(rule(H, [R]), Rules)
        ->  true
        ;   H = R
        ),
        replace(T, Rules, TR).
```